# Unpublished questions written on mobile site not showing on desktop site

Tags: bug, questions

When I write questions on the mobile Ask Ubuntu site but leave them unpublished, the question is saved on the mobile site, but I can't access it from the desktop site. I can access it on another mobile device. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I assume this is a bug.

**Update:** I can access questions written on the desktop site from the mobile site, but not the other way around.

I hope this can be fixed or solved before long.

Is anyone else having this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: How about using Android App on mobile?

Comment: I am trying out the app (which would not let me comment here, by the way), but I have certain reasons why I don't want to use it all of the time (which would require very a long discussion), and I also think that as the mobile site is supposed to have certain functionality, it is best that it works.

Comment: More [meta-tag:feature-request] than a bug, IMO.

Comment: I thought that it was a bug because it works the other way around.